# streamline react filter function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a filter function in React. The user would type a search term into the input and the list would filter correctly. However, when the user erased the last letter the list would not update back to the previous results. To remedy this I had to setState twice, once to render the original array of items, and once to render filtered items:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(users => {
        this.setState({ filteredUsers: users });
        this.setState({ users });
      });
  }
```

The filter function looks like this and is updated via `onChange` from the input:

```
  filterList = event => {
    let updateUsers = this.state.users;
    updateUsers = updateUsers.filter(user => {
      return (
        user.name.toLowerCase().search(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1
      );
    });
    this.setState({ filteredUsers: updateUsers });
  };
```

I then render the component with `filteredUsers`:

```
  render() {
    const { filteredUsers } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={this.filterList} />
        <div className="list">
          <List users={filteredUsers} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The question is whether I can streamline the process a bit without having to set State twice with the same data. Following DRY principles I find it unnecessary to do this, but fail to see how else I could make the filtering work.

Also, I plan on implementing several more filters to further limit search results, so the answer should have scalability in mind.

Check the components on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ko6yky6wvr)

Comment: can you add `List` component or else create codesandbox.io?

Comment: added to original

Comment: you can try `this.setState({users, filteredUsers: users });` instead of writing setState again.

Comment: @varit05 This does not save any resources

Comment: Did you replace it  in componentDidMount lifecycle. It was working fine for me!

Comment: I mean it does work, definitely. I'd want to focus on streamlining the process. While your solution works great, it is merely refactoring existing code. I would like a code which is more slim

Answer (score 0):

You can render `users` if there aren't `filteredUsers` yet. So you have one setState on `componentDidMount` and you render the list like this `<List users={filteredUsers || users} />`, with the initial state being `{ users: [] }`.

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xlp9lv53vw

Comment: and in this case, filteredUsers would take precedent over users, because it is first in the conditional? how does this work when there are filteredUsers but I erase a character from the search, wouldn't it still use the outdated filteredUsers?

Comment: @Helle Since you have an onChange handler, it will filter the users on each change, either it's erase a character or insert one, and it will setState with the filtered users. And since the component renders every time there is a change on state it will get each time the updated users. As for the conditional, an undefined or null value is falsy on the conditional so the first time it will get the users and on every change the filteredUsers.